# Progress of recursive functions on strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion, c-strings

I have been trying to understand process of recursion. Unfortunately, I can't get the solving method. I mean "*tracing*" of recursion on strings. Can you explain me why `&str[1]` is used ? How are `&str[1]` and the recursive function progressing ? I want to understand indeed. Thank you for all appreciated answers. I think I need all nuances.

```
/*Figure 10.4  Recursive Function to Count a Character in a String*/
/*
 *  Count the number of occurrences of character ch in string str
 */
int
count(char ch, const char *str)
{
      int ans;

      if (str[0] == '\0')                           /*  simple case  */
            ans = 0;
      else                      /*  redefine problem using recursion */
            if (ch == str[0])   /*  first character must be counted  */
                  ans = 1 + count(ch, &str[1]);
            else                /*  first character is not counted   */
                  ans = count(ch, &str[1]);

      return (ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `&str[1]` is same as `str + 1`.

Thus, function `count()` is called recursively, receiving as second argument a pointer to the next `char` in the string, until it meets `NULL`.

The rest of its functionality is pretty obvious. It counts how many times `ch` (the `char` passed as the first argument) is met in the string beginning at `str` (the pointer to `char` given on the second argument). If the currently pointed `char` (pointed by `*str`)  is `NULL`, then the value of `ans` so far is returned, because the end of the string is reached. Otherwise `ans` is increased or not depending on whether the currently pointed`char` (pointed by `*str`) is same as `ch` or not.

Comment: the string increment is never happening in the above code..@chrk. the same ch is compared every time with the same character of the str.

Comment: @Madan: It does. `&str[1]` is same as `&(*(str + 1))`, so on every call `*str` points to the next `char` in memory. Try it for yourself!

Comment: str[1] refer to the element at index 1 in the array str. then '&' operator refer to the address that is associated with the 1 element which remains same throughout the program execution.@chrk

Comment: @Madan: `*str` is a pointer to `char`. `str[1]` is  same as `*(str + 1)`, pointing the next `char` of `*str` in memory. `&str[1]` is its address, as it's same as `&(*(str + 1))`.

Comment: @Madan: `*str` doesn't remain  same throughout the program execution. On every call of `count()`, `*str` points to the next `char` in memory.

Comment: k i understood what you are saying. but think on this the str is the base address of the array that remains the same,consider 2020(address) for str. every time you do *(str+1) will be *(2020+1=2021) will remain same pointing to 2021 element.

Comment: @Madan: Actually it doesn't work that way. `*str` is just a pointer to `char`s in memory. So its value changes throughout the program's execution.

Answer (score 0):

&str[1] is used becuase everytime we call the function count again (recursion) we should start from the next char in the array after matching with the current char in the array.
when the function first executes it checks with str[0] then we send str[1] to the count and similarly next time we when we will pass str[1] then it will actually we mean to pass str[2] and so on till it reaches the last one which is NULL(\0).

Recursion is occuring at the call to the count function within count and we are doing str[1] so that the recursion ends at one point. If we dont do that the program will go in infinite loop.